# images not showing in UICollectionView from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I am returning from a very long time out and this was a previously working app so I'm assuming it's down to changes in the newer versions os iOS.

When I run the app on the simulator no images are displayed but the cells are being created and the names are being displayed. I know I must be missing something somewhere but can't for the life of me see it, however I'm not familiar with more recent changes.

Any help is much appreciated and this is my code:

```
- (void)createData {

    self.graniteImages = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self.graniteImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                  initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Angel Cream", @"name",
                                  @"angel-cream.jpg", @"image", nil]];
    [self.graniteImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                  initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Angola Black", @"name" ,
                                  @"angola_black1.jpg", @"image" , nil]];
    [self.graniteImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                  initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Angola Silver", @"name" ,
                                  @"angola-silver1.jpg", @"image" , nil]];

    [self.collectionView reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.graniteImages.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *graniteImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    graniteImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.graniteImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (_startingIndexPath) {
        NSInteger currentIndex = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - scrollView.bounds.size.width / 1) / scrollView.bounds.size.width) + 1;
        if (currentIndex < [self.graniteImages count]) {
            self.title = self.graniteImages[currentIndex][@"name"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can try and see if the imageNamed returns an actual image, maybe something happens with the assets, can you load those images by name, somewhere else?

Comment: Looks possible that your using the file name not the asset name.

Comment: Your images are in the assets file? Then try removing the '.jpg' extension. @JackRobinson is probably right, your image is likely not being loaded.

Comment: have you set tag of uiImageView and and image name should be in same in your asset or in bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

Was trying to be too organised with an image folder then sub folders for each category.

When I moved everything from the subfolders into just the image folder they all started showing!

Thanks for all your help guys!

Comment: @JackRobinson thanks for making me check I'd liked at so much code it was only after moving files which must have reindexed them that it worked... Many hours of frustration cured lol

Answer (score 0):

Are you build your project in storyboard? what's the debug information about `UICollectionViewCell` you created and graniteImageView returned from 
`[cell viewWithTag:100]`?
Make sure you added graniteImageView to cell and has correct frame, check your cell and image is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue.And my issue is resolved using below code.In this I created UIImageView programmatically

UIImageView *graniteImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];

```
graniteImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.graniteImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]];

graniteImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

graniteImageView.tag = indexPath.row;// Add here what tag you need

[cell addSubview:graniteImageView];
```